# If & Else statement executed concurrently

Tags: android, if-statement

I am using **if & else** condition to call the adapter depends on condition.Here inside of **if** I am calling data which was **filtered** for populationg it in ListView & inside of **Else** all the data has to be listed out. **But in my case both are executed.**

Your answer is more appreciated...

My Code is:

```
Restaurant_Beam filterBean = new Restaurant_Beam();
List<Restaurant_Beam> filterRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
if (Config.startFilterClicked == true) {     /*---Check whether the ToolBar Filter icon is clicked or not*/
    Config.startFilterClicked = false;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("startFilter", Config.startFilterClicked);
    editor.commit();

    Restaurant_Beam filter = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.listSuperHeroes.size(); i++) {
        filterBean = MainActivity.listSuperHeroes.get(i);

        int BeanPrice = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(filterBean.getIG_SALES_PRICE()));

        if (Filter_Frgament.strPriceFrom <= BeanPrice && BeanPrice <= Filter_Frgament.strPriceTo) {
            filter = new Restaurant_Beam(filterBean.getIG_PRODUCTID(), filterBean.getIG_PRODUCTNAME(),
                    filterBean.getIG_CATEGORY_ID(), filterBean.getIG_CATEGORYNAME(),
                    filterBean.getIG_SALES_PRICE(), filterBean.getIG_DELIVERY(),
                    filterBean.getIG_IMAGEURL(), filterBean.getIG_VOUCHER_ID(),
                    filterBean.getIG_LIKECOUNT(), filterBean.getIG_VOUCHEROFFER());

            filterRestaurant.add(filter);
            adapter = new CardAdapter(filterRestaurant, context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("Filter Product Price" + filterBean.getIG_PRODUCTID());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Filter Product Price" + " .***No" + "...1");
        }
    }
} else
    System.out.println("Filter Product Price" + " .***Yes**");
RestaurantDataSet = MainActivity.listSuperHeroes;
for (int i = 0; i < RestaurantDataSet.size(); i++) {
    adapter = new CardAdapter(RestaurantDataSet, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have brackets around the else block

Only the print out is part of it.

I believe that's what you intended to do

```
else{
System.out.println("Filter Product Price" + " .***Yes**");
RestaurantDataSet =     MainActivity.listSuperHeroes;
for (int i = 0; i < RestaurantDataSet.size(); i++) {
    adapter = new         CardAdapter(RestaurantDataSet, context);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: But still it is working same after using of else{ } @Angelo Oparah

Comment: Well that probably means that whatever happens within the else-block is a replica of what is inside the if block. I would suggest to trace the code within the if-block to see exactly what is happening there.

Comment: Yeah I checked.Listview is an empty before implementing Filter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to do your filtering if your filter button is pressed. And you want to run your "else" statement no matter what? If that's the case, you can have an `if` statement with no `else` statement so that you will always run the latter part of your code but only do the filtering if your button is pressed.

```
} else { <---- missing open bracket here
    System.out.println("Filter Product Price" + " .***Yes**");
    RestaurantDataSet = MainActivity.listSuperHeroes;
    for (int i = 0; i < RestaurantDataSet.size(); i++) {
        adapter = new CardAdapter(RestaurantDataSet, context);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
} <---- missing close bracket here
```

Comment: But If I press filter button,I need to execute only the if condition .. and no need to execute else. But in this case executed the both.

Comment: Are you saying you dont want both cases to run, but with your code your else is still getting run? If so, I think you are missing brackets for your `else` statement. I edited my answer to show you where you are missing brackets

Comment: But still it is working same after using of else{ } @richard song